# Transaction fees in ether transfer from coinbase to bittrex?

Tags: transactions, coinbase

I have transferred 0.1 ether from Coinbase to biitex and was charged 0.00042 ETH as transaction fee so ended up paying 0.10042 ETH.

Just now I have checked my balance in bittrex and found that I have only received 0.09308775 ether. Are there any other transaction fees that I am not aware of ?

Answer (score 1):

From [Bittrex FAQ](https://support.bittrex.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000199651-What-fees-does-Bittrex-charge-)

> Deposits - Please be aware that some
>   coins require us to move your funds to another address before we
>   credit them.  This means the coins network will charge you the normal
>   transaction fee for this send.  This is not something we can avoid.

You can read [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethtrader/comments/6ki3ij/tried_to_deposit_eth_in_to_bittrex_and_payed_13/) for a breakdown of why you have been charged that fee, as follows,

> So the way bittrex eth wallets work is that they have you send money
>   to the wallet and then they move the money to the bittrex wallet via a
>   smart contract. So that's already 2 transactions. An ethereum simple
>   transaction costs 21000 gas and at 70 Gwei gas price, which is high
>   (normal is 20GWei), that comes to 0.00147 ether for the first
>   transaction. The second transaction is sent to a smart contract, which
>   can tell the difference between ETH and ETC, so it is a little more
>   expensive to run, but also the cost is indeterminate, so they reserved
>   135546 for gas for the transaction, but only used 34470. The
>   transaction cost 0.00258525 Ether based on gas price of 75 GWei. The
>   reserved (unused) gas is still in the bittrex wallet ((135546 - 34470)
>   * 75 GWei = 0.0075807). which accounts for all of the missing ether. Fortunately, the 0.0075807 is still yours, but you need to contribute
>   more to the wallet to get it. The flat cost of contributing any amount
>   of ETH will be about 21000 * first gas price + 34470 * second gas
>   price ether, and there will always be an unclaimable amount around
>   101076 * second gas price ether. I see the same thing for my
>   contributions (albeit I had a lower gas price). The higher the gas
>   price, the faster it actually gets processed, so the exchanges keep
>   them high and adapt to the size of pending transactions. That all
>   means that if you contribute small amounts of ether, you are gonna pay
>   5%+ and if you contribute large amounts, you will see trivial amounts
>   of ether missing.

Comment: but wouldn't the advertised fee on Trex include all of this..?

Comment: @Joël, not really, as it is the fee for the internal (2nd) transaction. There is a really good discussion here on why and how, https://www.reddit.com/r/ethtrader/comments/6ki3ij/tried_to_deposit_eth_in_to_bittrex_and_payed_13/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid transfer fee from coinbase, transfer first to GDAX account and then transfer out to your other exchange of choice.  I buy all of my BTC, ETH, and LTC thru GDAX without any transaction fees and then transfer them out others (Binance, Poloniex, Bittrex, etc) without fees as well.

Comment: Good point. Instant buys/sells on GDAX have a 0.3% fee. Instant buy / sells on Coinbase have I think a 1% fee. But, if you place a buy/sell order below or above the most recent price Gdax, there should be a 0% fee -- however, it's indeterminate how long it will take to fill. Unfortunately, your answer doesn't explain the fee charged to the user by Bittrex.